# Android SoundPool: Play a stopped sound again

Tags: android, soundpool

I´m currently trying to play sounds in my android app with SoundPool API. Playing a sound is not the problem. Now I want to stop the sound and restart it later from beginning. But when i call the stop function and then play(), the sound is not played. Here is some code:

load the sound:

```
soundId = soundPool.load(context, fileId, 1);
```

play the sound:

```
streamId = soundPool.play(soundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, -1, 1);
```

stop the sound:

```
soundPool.stop(streamId);
```

I also tried to load the sound again before playing it a second time, but that didn´t fixed it.

When I use pause/resume the sound is played from the position where it was stopped (but I want it always from beginning).

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT:

I just figured out something strange. When I use soundpool.stop(), it works every second time I call soundpool.play(). So the first call of play() plays the sound, the second not, the 3rd, 5th, 7th.. call plays the sound.
When I use soundpool.pause() and then play(), it works every third time. So the 1st, 4th, 7th... call of play() starts the sound.

Is it a bug? Or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

i have created a simple project to do start and stop a sound and then play it again. here's the code

```
Button b1, b2;
private int streamId;
private int soundID;
private SoundPool sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    sp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID = sp.load(this, R.raw.middle, 1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.b1:
        streamId = sp.play(soundID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
        break;
    case R.id.b2:
        sp.stop(streamId);

        break;
    }
}
```

i worked properly in my case, if you are doing the same thing then problem may be somewhere else. If you could provide the some more detail then may be we can figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don´t hear anything when I use your code. When I change at the initiation of the SoundPool object "AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC" to "AudioManager.STREAM_RING" (like I use it in my app) I hear it every second time. Do I need some extra permission for STREAM_MUSIC? And could you please test if you have the same problem with STREAM_RING?

Comment: I have checked my code twice and its working properly for both 
 AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC and AudioManager.STREAM_RING. i would recommend you to create a sample project and test all the possibilities you want to or provide the exact implementation of soundPool in your current project.

Answer (score 0):

Play:

```
nowPlaying= soundPool.play(soundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, -1, 1); 

soundPool.stop(nowPlaying);
```

now reload it:

```
soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.yoursound, 0);
```